# Wordpress - Pass Reference Data of One Custom Post Type to a Form that Creates another CPT

Tags: post, get

I've been stuck on this and pulling my hair out.

I have an "Item Gallery" custom post type with a "Create Custom Item" button that will pass reference data to a PHP multi-page form. The form page is used to create a different custom post type (Custom-Item post). I am thinking I only need to pass hidden data of unique post-id and that this would be enough to retrieve "reference post-id", "reference post thumbnail", "reference url link".

---

REFERENCE POST PAGE (Item-Gallery Custom Post Type) I'm using WPViews content template for displaying this content.

Some fields that are displayed about item

->Submit Button "Create Custom Item" (Passes Post-ID, etc to Form Page)

```
<form action="../post-new" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="assocPostid" value="[wpv-post-id]">
<input type="hidden" name="assocPosturl" value="[wpv-post-url]">
<input type="hidden" name="assocPostimage" value="[wpv-post-featured-image]">
<input type="submit" value="Create Custom Item">
</form>
```

---

---

FORM PAGE (Custom-Item Custom Post Type)

**My Question: What code would I need here to display reference post info?**

*-Displays Reference Post Thumbnail*

*-Displays Reference ID (this will be saved to new CPT post)*

*-Displays Reference URL Link*

My Custom Form Inputs...

->Submit Button (Submits form data and reference data to new custom post type)

I have tried many failed attempts including the ones below to retrieve Reference POST data. Do I need to add some type of function for this process?

```
// Retrieve the hidden form variable.
$myvar = $_POST[wpv-post-id];
 echo "myvar: ".$myvar;

//-------More attempts   
<li>        
echo __($_POST['assocPostimage']);
</li> 
<li>
echo __($_POST['assocPostid']);
</li>
<li>    
echo __($_POST['assocPosturl']);
</li>

//----other attempts     
<li>
<?php _e('$POST','assoc-postid'); ?>
</li>

<li>    
<?php echo __('Associated Item'); ?>
</li> 

<li>
<p><input type="hidden" size="50" class="do_input_new full_wdth_me"   name="assoc-postid" placeholder="<?php _e('You have not added an item. You must     do this first.') ?>" value="<?php echo (empty($_POST['assoc-postid']) ? 
($post->assoc-postid == "Auto Draft" ? "" : $post->assoc-postid) :          $_POST['assoc-postid']); ?>" /></p>
</li>

<li>
Reference Item ID: <?php echo __($_POST ['assocPostid']); ?>
</li>
```

---

On reference post, I am thinking I only need to pass hidden data of unique post id and that this would be enough to later retrieve "reference post-id", "reference post thumbnail", "reference url link" for when individual custom-item post is displayed. I am using WP Views as a content template for individual reference post pages.